# Unable to access Android content provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I can see in LogCat that `ActivityManager` is reporting something about a particular content provider.  I use the following code to try to access that content provider in order to learn more about it:

```
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uriDSDS, null, null, null, null); 

    String[] columnNames = cursor.getColumnNames();        
    Log.d(TAG, "columnNames=" + columnNames.toString());
```

Unfortunately, after trying to get the cursor, I see the following error in LogCat:

> Failed to find provider for **__**

What's the problem?  Why can I not access this provider?  Could it be that access is restricted to certain apps?  Is there a way to go into ADB or something else to see all of the available content providers on the device?

Comment: Sorry for the obvious question, but what is `uriDSDS`?

Comment: It is a string I created for what appears to be a "dual sim" content provider.  I saw the string in logcat so I was hoping to attach to it.  Is there a way to find out all of the content providers that are available on my device so I can check the string to be certain I have the right one?

Comment: The URI for a content provider I am trying to query.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you add correct Uri
for example

Uri uriDSDS = Uri.parse(
                    "content://aaa.aaa/values");

Comment: Is there any way to verify you have the correct Uri?  Can you query a provider and see everything it offers somehow?

Answer (score 0):

As  in the working example below, do check if your uriDSDSis correct.

```
Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                        null);

                // get contact id
                while (people.moveToNext()) {
                    if (people != null) {
                        int numberFieldColumnIndex = people
                                .getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup._ID);
                        String number = people.getString(numberFieldColumnIndex);
                        contactId.add(number);
                    }
                }

                people.close();
```

Comment: How can I verify I have the correct URI?  Is there a way to browse all content providers on a given device?